# mySQL table with EMP_ID and lots of timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm new to relation databases and mySQL, I am trying to develop a database for employees, that logs all the times its employees access the system(shown by recording the timestamp of everytime it access the system).

So when the employee accesses the system, the current timeStamp is recorded, and the next time they acess it that current timestamp is also recorded. The idea is that i can go back and query how many times in a day an employee accessed the system or week and so on, for any employee.

so far i have:

```
EMP_ID | F_Name | L_Name | TimeStamp
-------------------------------------
1222   |  joe   |  blogs |  12.03.22
1222   |  joe   |  blogs |  12.44.34
1352   |  carl  |  mansy |  19.33.22
```

and so on, i would like to know if there is a way to have just one emp_id show up with all the timestamps below, or do i need another table? or can i just have the data base like this?

Obviously this will grow in size a lot, so would it be better to have a table for every emp_id?

Thanks in advance Jonny

Comment: Only one table, for all emp_id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all data is stored in table named `my_log_table`, To see all timestamps for an EMP_ID 12222, query it like

```
select TimeStamp from my_log_table where EMP_ID = 12222
```

Having all logs in same table would be scalable and easier to use. 

Issues with having multiple log tables:

- For each new user, you have to manually create a new table
- Privileges have to be granted to this script/user to query the new
  table created for a new user
- If EMP_ID changes, then you have to track and change table names

Moreover, you are not saving any space other than one column of EMP_ID of
   combined log table

Answer (score 1):

You should have 2 tables 
first one is the employee table

```
emplyee :   EMP_ID | F_Name | L_Name
```

the second one is the log table

```
employee_log : EMP_ID | TimeStamp
```

the first table will store the data of the empolyee 
the second will store just the log of this employee

and if you want to retrieve the logs you just need to join betwen these tables

```
select * from employee 
left join  employee_log on employee.EMP_ID  = employee_log.EMP_ID
```

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, one more question would be, if i use two tables how do i update the timestamp of employee log with the particular emp_id?

Comment: would i make the emp_id the foreign key in emp_log table?

Comment: you need to just insert new records in the log tables not update so you will know every time he accessed the system 
and if you want to get the last time he has log into the system use this query 
select max(TimeStamp) from employee_log  where EMP_ID  = ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have 2 tables one to store employee data and the other to store 
the log data

```
employee :   EMP_ID | F_Name | L_Name 

employee_log : EMP_ID | TimeStamp
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it would be better if you maintain your table as below.

### EMP_ID |  TimeStamp

1222   |   12.03.22
1222   |   12.44.34
1352   |   19.33.22

So, while retrieving you can display as cross table like below

### 1222       | 1352      |

12.03.22   | 19.33.22
12.44.34   |